# Apache configurations for Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, file-transfer

I am about to setup a reverse proxy server to filter and log page requests before relaying the actual content from the origin server.  (new to this)

Before this, I had the origin server public facing, and I had php5 configured to accept 20 Mb file uploads for my php web-app.

Now that I am sticking the proxy server in between, are there any special configurations that I should consider to make sure things such as file-transfer are still relayed properly between the client and the origin server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends very much on the reverse proxy you are using, as they tend to have different default max request body lengths.

e.g.

Apache - defaults to unlimited, it can be set using LimitRequestBody http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Nginx - defaults to 1MB, it can be changed using client_max_body_size http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size

Squid - defaults to unlimited, it can be set using request_body_max_size http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_body_max_size/

There may also be request body read timeouts, such as Nginx's client_body_timeout which is set to 60 seconds, which may affect people on slower/bad connections.

Comment: I am using Apache - I will look into the parameter you suggested and the same for time-out limits.  Thanks @Andy!

Comment: A note about the limitrequestbody:
Note: not applicable to proxy requests.
Per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: @user235375 Was the documentation changed in the meantime? I don't see anything about proxy at "LimitRequestBody".  So I conclude that it works with Apache 2.2 even with proxy requests.